# Connecting chatbot using botpress with mysql

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I'm trying to build a chatbot using Botpress. I'm a beginner, looking for your help. One of the requirements is to query database to answer questions. i use mysql als Database. could some one help me with on the Topic?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you're (still) trying to create a chatbot which answers some predefined questions, there is a module for that named "QNA" (for "questions and answers").
You can find it here : https://github.com/botpress/botpress/tree/master/modules/qna

Don't forget to use the NLU module too (natural language understanding) if it is not activated.
The NLU module is here : https://github.com/botpress/botpress/tree/master/modules/nlu

Comment: And for the MySQL connection part, [this link from the botpress documentation](https://botpress.io/docs/10.50/recipes/dbs/) will probably help you

Answer (score 1):

You can use a custom action to create a MySQL database utility which can be used to connect and perform DB operations on your MySQL database.

In your custom action use knex and connect to DB

```
const knex = require('knex')({
    client: 'mysql',
    connection: {
      host: 'localhost',
      user: 'root',
      password: 'lamepassword',
      database: 'sys'
    },
    useNullAsDefault: false,
    log: {
      warn(message) {
        console.log(message);
      },
      error(message) {
        console.error(message);
      },
      deprecate(message) {
        console.log(message);
      },
      debug(message) {
        console.log(message);
      },
    }
  });

await knex.raw(query).on('query', function (data) {
      console.log("Executing: " + data.sql)
}).then(function (data) {
  if (data.length == 2 && name === 'get') {
    user.data = data[0][0][key]
  } else if (data.length == 2 && name === 'set') {
    user.data = undefined;
  } else if (data.length == 2 && name === 'update') {
    console.log(data)
  } else {
    user.data = undefined;
  }
}).catch(err => console.log(err));
```

For more details please check below demo and [this tutorial](https://aabingunz.com/how-to-connect-to-mysql-database-using-botpress/)

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zIVnE6bEXZQ